# In Vi editor if we have seen $ so what is the mean that?

Tags: vim, vi

**This is the output of file1 in vi editor -**

```
xyz|123|2013-12-22|2014-02-28
xyz|123|2013-12-29|2014-01-04
xyz|123|2013-12-29|2014-01-04
xyz|123|2013-12-29|2014-01-04
xyz|123|2013-12-29|2014-01-04
xyz|123|2013-12-29|2014-01-04
xyz|123|2013-12-29|2014-01-04
```

*so at the end of each line i get '$' so what it mean end of line.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see the `$` symbol at the end of each line (and no matter what you do, you can't put the cursor on that symbol) that means that vim is showing you where the newline characters are in the file.

This is controlled by the `list` option:

```
:set list
:set nolist
```

Further, the `listchars` option tells vim what symbols to use for these newline and other special characters.